# No sound from heaphone jack on an Asus X92V

Tags: sound

A friend has just installed Xubuntu on my laptop (ASUS Z92V). The laptop speakers work but there is no sound coming out of the headphone jack. I use the laptop as an internet radio, CD player and all, can anybody help?

PS I am not an IT expert, so please talk to me like you would to a 5yo!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `alsamixer` from terminal, and enable surround, or shared jack (sorry I had this problem with my laptop, and it is not here) with the M button. (You can use the arrow keys to go left-right.

Edit: I have the Duplicate Front. If you see this, then your problem can be solved.
[image: Duplicate front in alsamixer]

Comment: Thanks. Surround was already enabled and I can't see any 'shared jack'. Still no sound

Comment: Can you see Duplicate or something like that?

Comment: I've just had a look, I can see: master, pcm,front, surround, center, lfe, line, cd, mic, spdif, spdif d, beep and channel. All enabled

Comment: When I get my laptop back (after next week), I will check there, and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good audio debugging guides on the Ubuntu Wiki [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio)